# How to customize session data for server side in Next-Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Added extra fields for `client` side `session` in `next-auth` but `getServerSession` still returning default payload. I'm unable to get how to do it in their docs & little bit googling.

Following is the default session data

```js
user: {
      name: 'Super Adminsss',
      email: 'admin@gmail.com',
      image: undefined
    }
```

I want

```js
user: {
      name: 'Super Adminsss',
      email: 'admin@gmail.com',
      image: undefined,
      otherField: ['one','two']
    }
```

I'm using **TypeScript 5.2.2** **Next.js 13.4**